# Style a required input tag on deselect if the tag is empty

Tags: html, css, forms

I have an input tags that might look something like

```
<input required pattern="..." >
```

I want to style this tag differently(red around the borders) if it is empty or if the field does not match the pattern, but only if the field has already been visited.

---

1. If I open the page containing the form, I want all the fields to be styled normally.
2. If I click on a required field, and then either

   - press tab
   - click on another field
   - or submit the form

   while the field is either

   - still empty
   - or filled with invalid input, or click on another field

Then want want this field to be styled differently

---

I know about the `:required` and `:invalid` pseudoclass tags, but I don't know how to restrict this to only fields that have been visited already, because the `:visited` tag only applies to links

Comment: @Spectric What do you mean pattern doesn't work?

Comment: Sorry. I thought that was a date input. My apologies :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a focus event listener for each input that adds a class that you can style when :invalid. That way the invalid styling would never be applied unless the "has been in focus" class is present.

```js
const inputEmail = document.getElementById('email');
const inputNumber = document.getElementById('number');

inputEmail.addEventListener('focus', () => {
  inputEmail.classList.add('has-been-focused');
});

inputNumber.addEventListener('focus', () => {
  inputNumber.classList.add('has-been-focused');
});
```

```css
input {
  outline: none;
}

.has-been-focused:invalid {
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<input id="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" required />
<input id="number" placeholder="Number" type="number" required />
```